# Custom Sphinx directive gives a pickling error

Tags: python-sphinx

I am trying to register a custom Sphinx directive on my `conf.py`, like this:

```
diff --git a/docs/conf.py b/docs/conf.py
index fda031a72..2d829602d 100644
--- a/docs/conf.py
+++ b/docs/conf.py
@@ -2,6 +2,10 @@ import os
 import sys
 from configparser import RawConfigParser
 
+from docutils import nodes
+from docutils.parsers.rst import directives
+from docutils.parsers.rst.directives.admonitions import BaseAdmonition
+
 import sphinx_rtd_theme
 
 sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
@@ -153,5 +157,18 @@ linkcheck_ignore = [
 ]
 
 
+class commercial(nodes.Admonition, nodes.Element):
+    pass
+
+
+class Commercial(BaseAdmonition):
+
+    node_class = commercial
+
+
 def setup(app):
     app.add_css_file('css/sphinx_prompt_css.css')
+
+    app.add_node(commercial)
+
+    directives.register_directive('commercial', Commercial)
```

but my `make html` fails with this error:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/home/juanlu/Projects/RTD/readthedocs.org/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 501, in write_doctree
    pickle.dump(doctree, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'commercial'>: attribute lookup commercial on builtins failed
```

full traceback: https://pastebin.com/fgHdDpJK

Anybody knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, see [this issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6751), and [this one](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1493), and [this one](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1424), and [these docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/todo.html#writing-the-extension):

> It is important to know that while you can extend Sphinx without leaving your `conf.py`, if you declare an inherited node right there, you’ll hit an unobvious **PickleError**. So if something goes wrong, please make sure that you put inherited nodes into a separate Python module.